# Finding a number ( to be read from keyboard) in the list , where the size of list and the list is to be read from the keyboard

Tags: c

I am not able to figure out the error in the following code where I want to check a number in the list, the code prints yes, if it's present, and no if not. The output that I receive is random yes and no. Sometimes it's correct but other times, it's wrong.

```
{
    int n, N, a[n], i, flag = 0;
    printf("n , N\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &N);
    printf("a\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == N)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag == 0)
        printf("No\n");
    else
        printf("Yes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to take an array with size n, which the user will input afterwards in the code and simultaneously while declaring the size I am entering the value of N, which is to be found in the list .. then using for loop I am comparing every number stored, but I think here the code fails.

Comment: When you define the array `a`, what is the value of `n`? The statements are executed in the order you write them, so array definitions will not be remade retroactively. And to answer my own question: Uninitialized non-static local variables will have an *indeterminate* value (look at them as garbage).

Comment: You don't need `printf()` to produce the desired output. The `f` is for _formatting_ and you do not format anything, just output a plain text. In this case `puts()` is enough: `puts(flag ? "Yes" : "No");` (be aware `puts()` appends new line character).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem statement says you need to find out whether the value given as `N` exists among the `n` values given. It does not require you to *store* those `n` values.

So it's enough to check each of them as soon as it arrives and ...abandon it, memorizing just a positive result of test. No array needed.

Here is a simplified implementation:

```c
    int n, N, a, i, flag = 0;

    puts("n , N");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &N);

    puts("a");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a);
        if(a == N)
            flag = 1;
    }

    puts(flag ? "Yes" : "No");
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, try to understand what 'some programmer dude' commented on your post. There is a bug in your code. You declared the array `a[n]`, while the variable `n` is not initialized yet. So at first, you need to declare a pointer `*a`, then take the size of the array as an input from the user, and then finally allocate memory in pointer `*a` with the `malloc()` function. So here is the working code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n, N, *a, i, flag = 0;
    printf("n , N\n");
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &N);

    a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    printf("a\n");
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if(a[i] == N)
        {
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    free(a);
    if(flag == 0)
        printf("No\n");
    else
        printf("Yes\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why replace `a[n]` with `a = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * n);` ? BTW it should be `a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`, the return value of malloc should not be casted, it's useless.

Comment: You are right. The cast is useless. Anyway, it doesn't make a difference though. And the reason you need to replace `a[n]` with `a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * n)` is that the variable `n` was not initialized yet. It contained garbage value, so `a[n]` would crash the program.

Comment: You should *free* the allocated memory at the end.

Comment: @ProgrammerHobbyist who not simply keep `int a[n]` and put if _after_ the `scanf`_?

Comment: Alright, that works as well! But if he really needed to declare the array before he took input from the user, then malloc() would be necessary. And the asker should know this thing, as he is a beginner.

Comment: @Jabberwocky That's what I would personally recommend. Unless the value of `n` happens to be "large".

Comment: @ProgrammerHobbyist no one _needs to declare the array before he took input from the user_. A variable needs to be declared when it needs to be declared.

Comment: Then why does `malloc()` exist? (Asking seriously! Not to quarrel with you.)

Comment: The problem statement does not clearly specify the value sought `N` should be input _before_ the list, but the attempted solution suggests that's how it should work. If so, you do not need `malloc()` and even an array – just scan the input for `n` values and compare them as they come. The only result needed is 'the value appeared in the stream', the whole stream needn't be archived.